# Inserting an item to dynamic dictionary is not working

Tags: c

As a learning exercise, I'm trying to implement my own dictionary in C. My dictionary type definition is:

```
#define MAXCAP 24

static size_t primes[MAXCAP + 2] = {
    1,
    101,       251,       509,         1021,      2039,     4093,     8191,
    16381,     32749,     65521,       131071,    262139,   524287,   1048573,
    2097143,   4194301,   8388593,     16777213,  33554393, 67108859, 134217689,
    268435399, 536870909, 10737441789, 2147483647};

typedef struct item_tag item;

struct item_tag {
    void *key;
    void *val;
    item *next;
};

typedef struct dict_tag {
    size_t cap; // capacity of the dict, which is used as an index for primes[]
    size_t size; // number of slots taken up out of the capacity of the dict 
    item **items;
    int (*eq) (const void *, const void *);
    int (*hash) (const void *, size_t n);
} dict;
```

My function for inserting a new entry to the dict is:

```
int dict_put(void *key, void *val, dict *d) {
    int i;
    item *kv;

    if (!dict_get(key, d)) {
        kv = malloc(sizeof(item));
        kv->key = key;
        kv->val = val;
        kv->next = d->items[(i = d->hash(key, primes[d->cap]))];
        d->items[i] = kv;
        if (!kv->next)
            d->size++;
        if (d->size >= primes[d->cap] / 2)
            expand(d);
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Insertion works fine if I do not try to resize the dict using `expand` function which is defined as:

```
static void expand(dict *d) {
    int i;
    item *kv;
    dict *tmp;

    if (d->cap < MAXCAP) {
        tmp = malloc(sizeof(dict));
        init(d->cap + 1, d->hash, d->eq, tmp);
        for (i = 0; i < d->cap; i++) {
            for (kv = d->items[i]; kv; kv = kv->next)
                dict_put(kv->key, kv->val, tmp);
        }
        destroy_items(0, d);
        d->cap = tmp->cap;
        d->size = tmp->size;
        d->items = tmp->items; // looks like there are no items in dict after this step
        free(tmp);
    } else
        fprintf(stderr, "dict: max size reached.\n");
}
```

In the above function, I'm trying to create a new temporary larger dict and then copy the pointer to the new list of items to the old dict. The `init` function is:

```
static void init(size_t n, const int (*hash) (const void *, size_t n), const int (*eq) (const void *, const void *),
                 dict *d) {
    d->cap = n;
    d->size = 0;
    d->eq = eq;
    d->hash = hash;
    d->items = calloc(primes[d->cap], sizeof(item *));
}
```

Comment: My suggestion is that you change the array name from `primes` to `capacity`, and member `cap` to `capIndex`, since `d->cap` **is not** the capacity of the dictionary, it's just an index into the array. It's `capacity[d->capIndex]` that gives you the capacity of the dictionary. BTW, there's a hint in there somewhere as to the source of the error. And for future reference, you'll have better luck (i.e. faster response) if you post a [mcve].

Comment: Tip: consider `d->items = calloc(primes[d->cap], sizeof(item *));` --> `d->items = calloc(primes[d->cap], sizeof d->items[0]);`, then would not have to look some 30- 60 lines up to review if code used the right type.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica thanks for the tip. When I try this I get the warning "suspicious usage of sizeof(A*); pointer to aggregate". Is it okay to ignore that?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I changed it to `d->items = calloc(primes[d->cap], sizeof(d->items+0));` and it's okay now (based on [doc](https://clang.llvm.org/extra/clang-tidy/checks/bugprone-sizeof-expression.html). Thanks for your advice!

Comment: @kovac `sizeof(d->items+0)` is the size of the wrong type.  Should be `sizeof d->item[0]` or `sizeof *(d->items)`.   `sizeof(d->items+0)` is the sizeof of a _pointer_.  What is needed here is the size of what it points to.

Comment: @kovac "I get the warning "suspicious usage of sizeof(A*);" is unclear as [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71985131/inserting-an-item-to-dynamic-dictionary-is-not-working?noredirect=1#comment127199594_71985131) does not suggest that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is on this line in the `expand` function

```
for (i = 0; i < d->cap; i++) {
```

should be changed to

```
for (i = 0; i < primes[d->cap]; i++) {
```